# How to know datatable has all values which are in list object using QuestionID c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, datatable

**Here is the code example :**

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("QuestionID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ElementValue", typeof(string));

DataRow r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "238";
r1[1] = "text";
dt.Rows.Add(r1);

r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "111";
r1[1] = "text";
dt.Rows.Add(r1);

r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "605";
r1[1] = "date";
dt.Rows.Add(r1);

r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "123";
r1[1] = "text"; 
dt.Rows.Add(r1); 

r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "562";
r1[1] = "text"; 
dt.Rows.Add(r1); 
r1 = dt.NewRow();
r1[0] = "938";
r1[1] = 938; 
dt.Rows.Add(r1);
```

**And List object :**

```
class keyValue
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

List<keyValue> k_v = new List<keyValue>();
            {
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "238", value = "value_238" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "111", value = "value_111" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "605", value = "value_605" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "123", value = "value_123" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "901", value = "value_901" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "562", value = "value_562" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "938", value = "value_938" };
                new keyValue { QuestionID= "911", value = "value_911" };
            }
```

How can I check if `listObject` satisfies `DataTable` (has all questionIDs ) and All QuestionId must be presented in `DataTable`?

Comment: I assume that what you mean by that last part ("*All questionId must be presented in DataTable*) is that questions are defined there - so your only task is to check if all questions from the table have been loaded into the list - is that correct?

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct @Kjartan

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you have a specific reason to do so, don't implement your own list of key value pairs; use `Dictionary<string, string>()` instead.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("123", "question").
```

Given that, you can check if a key exists easily:

```
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
    bool isKeyLoaded = dict.ContainsKey(row[0]);
}
```

Comment: I actually get that list object from database so it has to be list